# Preserving the load history when re-creating pipes in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is there any way to preserve the load history when re-creating pipes (using `CREATE OR REPLACE`)?

We do a lot of automated CI/CD on Snowflake, and sometimes pipes need to get re-created. When this happens, the load history is lost. Right now, the [accepted workaround](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-snowpipe-manage.html#recreating-pipes) is a manual process, which doesn't work very well in an automated workflow.

This makes refreshing pipes dangerous, as duplicate data could be loaded. There is also a danger of losing some notifications/files while the pipe is being re-created -- with or without the manual process, automated or not (which is unacceptable, for obvious reasons).

I wish there was a simple parameter to enable this. Something like:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PIPE my_pipe
  PRESERVE_HISTORY = [ TRUE | FALSE ]
AS <copy_statement>
```

An alternative to this would be an option/parameter for pipes to share the load history with the table instead. This way, when the pipe is re-created (but the table isn't), the load history is preserved. If the table is dropped/truncated, then the load history for both the table and the pipe would be lost.

Another option would be the ability to modify pipes using an `ALTER` command instead, but currently this is [very limited](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/alter-pipe.html#usage-notes). This way, we wouldn't even need to re-create the pipe in the first place.

***EDIT:*** Tried automating the manual process with a procedure, but there's a still chance of losing notifications.

Comment: `Right now, the accepted workaround is a manual process...` Is there anything in your CI/CD process that would prevent this from being automated by something like a stored procedure? The most likely step of the 7 would be any changes to the notifications from the cloud host, but if they could be passed into an SP as a parameter, this could probably be automated.

Comment: Ah, good point!  I didn't think about this at all!  We shouldn't have to worry about the notifications from the cloud host (AWS), as we're simply sending them directly to the SQS queue generated by Snowflake (which is the same for the entire account).

Comment: Well, just tried this, and there's a major issue: notifications are missed if received between the pausing/last status check of the pipe and its re-creation. By automating the process with a procedure, we can shrink the window... but not eliminate it.  We can see those notifications in the `numOutstandingMessagesOnChannel` property of the pipe status, but I can't find much more information about this, nor how to get those notifications processed.

Comment: I'm not sure about this, but you can try refreshing the pipe in a way that only picks up the changes of interest:  `alter pipe mypipe refresh modified_after = '2021-09-13 01:05:15.123456789'` You'd just need to hold on to the time when the pipe got suspended (before being recreated) and use it for the refresh. Fingers crossed 

Comment: Yup, I'm working on something along those lines!  I want to be really careful to avoid duplicating data though, so I'm working on a way to detect specifically which files haven't been ingested (using the [`LIST`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/list.html) command + [`COPY_HISTORY`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/copy_history.html)). We're also prefixing all our files with a date path (`YYYY/MM/DD/HH`), so that will help.

Comment: I'd be interested to see what you come up with. Please post as an answer when done.

Comment: @GregPavlik: Answer posted below! If you posted your timestamp idea as an answer, I'd give it a vote! 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since preserving the load history doesn't seem possible currently, I explored a few alternatives:

***tl;dr: [Here is the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69199826/4406793).***

##### Deleting/Removing/Moving the files after ingestion

- Thank you @patrick_at_snowflake for the recommendation!
- This turned out to be a bit tricky to do with high reliability, because there's no simple way to tie the ingestion of files in Snowflake to their deletion/removal in could storage (i.e. life cycle management policies are not aware of whether or not the files were ingested successfully by Snowpipe).
- It could be possible to monitor the ingestion using a [stream](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/streams.html) or [COPY_HISTORY](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/copy_history.html) as a trigger for the deletion/removal of the files, but this is not simple (would probably require the use of an [external function](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/external-functions-introduction.html)).

##### Refreshing a subset of the pipe

- Thanks @GregPavlik for the suggestion!
- The idea here would be to save the timestamp at which the initial pipe is paused/dropped. This timestamp could then be used to refresh the new pipe with a "safe" subset of the staged files (in order to avoid re-ingesting the same files and creating duplicates records).
- I think this is a great idea (my favorite so far), but I also had monitoring in mind and wanted to confirm that this would work, so I continued exploring alternatives for a while.

##### Replaying the missed notifications

- I asked a separate question about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69195382).
- The idea would be to simply replay the notifications that were neither processed by the initial pipe or the new pipe.
- However this doesn't seem possible either.

##### Monitoring the load of every staged file

- Finally, I arrived at [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69199826/4406793).
- This is the one I went with as it not only allows to refresh missing files, but also to monitor the loading of all staged files as a whole (no matter the source of the failure).
- I was already working on monitoring Snowpipe as part of a project, so this solution added another layer of monitoring.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a pipe creates a new object with its own history, I don't see how this is something that would be feasible to do.

Why do you need to re-create the pipes?

Your other option is to manage the source files, after content is ingested by a pipe remove the files that were ingested. The new pipe won't even know about the new files. This, of course, can be automated too

Comment: `Why do you need to re-create the pipes?` --> To alter the data loading in any way (not doable using an `ALTER` command at the moment). It's something we can avoid as much as possible, but does need to happen sometimes. We won't delete the source files as those serve as our tertiary backups.

Comment: You don't need to delete them, but move them to an archived space, even setting up an arbitrary life cycle management policy on your cloud platform would work